# Comparing branches in bitbucket web ui depends on the ordering

Tags: git, bitbucket

In the bitbucket web ui you can compare two branches and see the diff. But the diff depends on the order of the branches.

Why does:

```
Source: branchA
Target: branchB
```

give a different diff than:

```
Source: branchB
Target: branchA
```

?

Comment: Can you give examples about what kind of differences you see?

Comment: Note that in the webui, the order dictates which branch you merge **into** which other branch. It is not deemed important which changes the target branch would bring to the table, you're merging the source branch into it, it is important which changes the source branch applies to the target branch.

Comment: Basically, the webui focuses on showing "which changes will I get into my target branch if I merge the source branch into it". Thus, there will be differences depending on which direction you consider merging.

Comment: As a simple example. If branchA adds a file, and branchB modifies a file, the act of merging A into B will show an additional file, but no changes to the file modified in B. Whereas merging B into A will show changes to the file, but nothing about the added file.

Comment: Now you say "source" twice in each example, you mean source + target, right?

Comment: So based on above comments its expected behavior. But what if I just want to do a plain diff between the tip of two branches?

Comment: Don't think bitbucket will do it for you. Personally I'd do `git difftool -d branchA branchB` locally, and I have configured difftool to use Beyond Compare. This will pop open a directory comparison (`-d`) that has all the files and folders that are missing from either side or has been changed. The only difference with regards to the order of the branches in that tool is which folder appears on the left vs. the right side.

Comment: Ok that is also what I am used to. It seems that the compare view in bitbucket is a "special" bitbucket feature that does not have corresponding command in  vanilla/plain git from command line?